# IOS Unable to instantiate the UIApplication delegate instance

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I created a new cocos2d project and copied a number of files from a previous project into this new project. I made sure to indicate that I wanted a copy when prompted by xCode.
My AppDelegate class is AppDelegate.

I did a clean and the a build on the new project.

My main.m looks like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
[pool release];
return retVal;
}
```

When I run the new project, I get the following error;

Unable to instantiate the UIApplication delegate instance. No class named AppDelegate is loaded.

This error appears to occur when

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
```

is being run in the main.m file.

The class AppDelegate clearly exists in my project. I was hoping someone could nudge me in the right direction here.

Comment: Is AppDelegate included in the compile step of your target's Build Phases?  (Click on the target in Xcode and go to the Build Phases tab.)

Comment: In addition to @PhillipMills excellent suggestion, a few other things you can check: are you absolutely sure that the class name (not just the name of the file) of your app delegate is simply "AppDelegate"?  If it is, I'm thinking Phillip is on the right track.

Comment: Phillip, you hit it on the head. I actually had a number of files missing from the 'Compile Sources' section of Build Phase. This tip was very informative. Thank you very much for taking the time.
Also, thank you WendiKidd for the assistance.